# Downloading APK via browser on Android device and then opening it give "Cannot open File"

Tags: android, apk

I am trying to beta test a app with a few people. I have put it on my site.

I now go to that site and click the link to download the APK. The apk downloads and i see it in the notification bar. When i click it i get an error "Cannot Open File"

Browser: Chrome
Android: 4.4 S4 mini
Webserver: Glassfish

If i got to Astro and open the same file from there it does open the installer and ask to install the file. How can i get it to work via the website and stop getting the "Cannot Open File" error.

Comment: What MIME type is your server putting in the `Content-type` HTTP header for this download?

Comment: how do i check that? i have put application/vnd.android.package-archive in glassfish but not sure if it took

Comment: Use something like **`curl`**, or your Firebug/Chrome Inspector/etc. sorts of tools, or tools like the ones [the W3C lists](http://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-headers-charset), etc.

Comment: just checked with Poster in firefox. Content Type: application/vnd.android.package-archive

Comment: Well, that should be OK. Is this a direct download, or is your server doing some fancy `Content-disposition` stuff?

Comment: direct download (ie: www.mysite.com/app.apk)